# Is there any advantage to an incremental rehash?

Tags: data-structures, hashtable

I'm taking a college course on data structures. After the section of lectures on hash tables, our teacher has assigned a project, which is pretty much just making a hash table with some extra bits. One thing that I noticed is that he has specified that when we rehash the table, it must be done 25% at a time.

The object holds another array and when we need to rehash, we move the current array to the extra space, and then resize the 'current' array. The rehash function then moves 25% of the old array to the new, and moves another 25% on each insert and removal. Other than spreading out the impact of needing to rehash over multiple operations, is there any advantage to this?

Comment: Please share a diagram or some way of showing us what your hashtable looks like - because I'm unsure what you mean by _"The object holds another array"_

Answer (score 0):

While 25% may not be very interesting. You could get the table to rehash gradually to avoid paying the cost all at once. Having a second table where you are adding new keys and moving the old ones shouldn't be too expensive.

However, you should look at the impact of NOT rehashing. The main reason we do rehashing is because the load factor is getting unacceptably high. If you don't rehash, you'll be doing a lot of scanning looking for the value you want. And your O(1) performance could degrade to O(N). So postponing rehashing could actually be more harmful than helpful.

My guess is that your professor is tweaking the algorithm so that you learn more aspects about it and can't merely copy a solution from the internet. Basically it's a learning exercise.

Comment: "If you don't rehash, you'll be doing a lot of scanning looking for the value you want." - it can be worse, for open addressing / closed hashing implementations, as load factor approaches or reaches 1 you get to the point where you can't insert new elements, rather than the degradation towards O(N) seen for separate chaining.

Answer (score 0):

> Other than spreading out the impact of needing to rehash over multiple operations, is there any advantage to this?

Not really.  That alone is quite a significant advantage though, for certain use cases where worst-case performance is important.  (It's often more useful in such cases to move a small number of elements on each subsequent `insert` (and optionally `erase`), rather than a largish fraction of the table.)

I say "not really" rather than "no" because in some pretty contrived use cases it could avoid some cost - for example, if you start the rehashing, migrating 25% of elements, then `clear()` the data structure before doing another `insert` or `erase`, you've avoided having to migrate the other 75% of elements to the new array.